# Enumeration Javascript example confusion

Tags: javascript, for-loop, enumeration

I am a little confused regarding enumeration in javascript by the following example.

```
var property;

for(property in Object){
  console.log("Name "+property);
  console.log("Value "+Object[property]);
}
```

I am confused by this example. Can somebody please explain how it should work?

Answer (score 1):

The `for..in` operator iterates over the properties of an object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

```
var property;

for(property in Object){
    console.log("Name "+property);
    console.log("Value "+Object[property]);
}
```

The word `Object` refers to the constructor function for the object type, and has no properties. So the above outputs nothing.